# When does the day end in The Four Kings Casino and Slots?

Tags: four-kings-casino

In this game you can complete daily missions and spin a special slot machine once a day. When does the day end in this game so I can spin again?

Answer (score 1):

According to the developer, the day ends at 0:00 GMT.

See e.g. [this](http://everytimezone.com/#2015-6-5,-720,cn3) page to convert it your timezone.

[Source](http://steamcommunity.com/app/260430/discussions/0/618463738387865724/)